# Looking for a sci-fi book with lot of mechs

Tags: story-identification

I read it about 2013-14, and it was a hardback book with two robots and a kid on a ‘skateboard’ that could fly. Printed in english with no illustrations I can remember inside the book.

Things I remember

- there was this thing called “Maker’s Sight” that the main character and his dad had, but his dad said to keep secret.
- kid stows away on a mech after pirates claimed the mech (was his favorite mech)
- was some sort of time collapse, with 3 types of people (past [think they were called elders?], present and future)
- someone was trying to reverse the time collapse, but he was a tyrant (I think. He might be the antagonist)
- Pirates have 2 ships, a destroyer analog and a barge being towed by the destroyer.
- went to an island and the pirates found out about the skateboard.
- kid seemed to have friends

Comment: So, based on the time and the lack of illustrations, _not_ [*Diego and the Rangers of the Vastlantic*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23354816-timeless) then?  (It matches the flying skateboard, the time collapse and chapter 10 is called "Maker's Sight.")

Comment: @DavidW, yes thank you! Can you put it as the answer. I knew it had something like Atlantic in the name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's possible you're off by a few years, this sounds very much like [*Diego and the Rangers of the Vastlantic*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2247243) (2017) by Armand Baltazar.  The cover depicts the hero on a flying board and a giant robot:

[image: Cover of "Diego and the Rangers of the Vastlantic" showing the hero and one of his friends on flying boards in front of a harbour with a sailing ship, a giant robot and a dinosaur]

Snippets of reviews on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23354816-timeless) show many matches to your points:

> 13 year old **Diego and his friends** are the first generation to be born into the world after **the Time Collision**, when continents and times collided. Now things have settled enough, but not entirely; people still **identify themselves as from one of three major time periods**, and dinosaurs roam the oceans and wild lands. The present is full of tech from multiple eras, and **Diego's father is a genius engineer** who (among other things) builds robots. Diego has his abilities--including **a mystic ability that allows him to make almost any repair**--but isn't sure he wants the same life. His mother was a hotshot pilot in the wars that broke out after the Collision, and Diego's more interested in flying. Then **Diego's father is kidnapped** by a group that wants to **reverse the Time Collision (which will wreak havoc on the current timeline)**, and Diego and three other 13-14 year olds accidentally end up on the rescue mission--led by **the pirates** paid for the job.
>
> <sub>[Review ref](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/2304891094)</sub>

Another notes Diego has the Maker's Sight:

> On his thirteenth birthday, Diego learns from his father that **special abilities called "The Maker's Sight" run in their family**, which grant them the skill of visualizing the design and creation of objects within their mind, talents that Diego's father also possesses.
>
> <sub>[Review ref](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/2146301127)</sub>

(Note that the editions listed on ISFDb were all illustrated, so yours may have had different cover art.)

Comment: I’m definitely off a few years. When I read it was really fuzzy